# My submit form by jQuery ajax() in Codeigniter failed

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

please help me , please ...... I read many tutorials in stackoverflow or other website about codeigniter , but I don't find anything can solve my problem , please teach me guys.

this is my code for Jquery ajax function, this file include in the view with form

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {


 $("#Nama").focus();
 
 $("#tglLahirPemohon").datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  yearRange: "-100:+20",
 });
    $( "#anim" ).change(function() {
      $( "#tglLahirPemohon" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "slideDown" );
    });
 
 $("#tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon").datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 yearRange: "-50:+0",
 });
 
    $( "#anim" ).change(function() {
      $( "#tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "slideDown" );
    });
    
     $("#tglKeluarPaspor").datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 yearRange: "-50:+0",
 });
 
    $( "#anim" ).change(function() {
      $( "#tglKeluarPaspor" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "slideDown" );
    });
    
     $("#masaBerlakuPaspor").datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 yearRange: "-50:+0",
 });
 
    $( "#anim" ).change(function() {
      $( "#masaBerlakuPaspor" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "slideDown" );
    });
     $("#masaBerlakuVisa").datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 yearRange: "-50:+0",
 });
 
    $( "#anim" ).change(function() {
      $( "#masaBerlakuVisa" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "slideDown" );
    });
     $("#masaBerlakuKartu").datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 yearRange: "-50:+0",
 });
 
    $( "#anim" ).change(function() {
      $( "#masaBerlakuKartu" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "slideDown" );
    });
    
     $("#tanggalLahirAyah").datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 yearRange: "-100:+0",
 });
 
    $( "#anim" ).change(function() {
      $( "#tanggalLahirAyah" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "slideDown" );
    });
    
     $("#tanggalLahirIbu").datepicker({
 changeMonth: true,
 changeYear: true,
 yearRange: "-100:+0",
 });
 
    $( "#anim" ).change(function() {
      $( "#tanggalLahirIbu" ).datepicker( "option", "showAnim", "slideDown" );
    });
    
    $("#simpan").click(function(){
  var cek = $(".cek:checked");
  var string = $("#my-form").serialize();

   
  if(cek.length==0){
   $('.bottom-right').notify({
    message: {text: 'Maaf, Jenis dokumen tidak boleh kosong'},type:'info'
   }).show();
   return false();
  }
   
  
  $.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url  : "<?php echo site_url(); ?>/peserta/home/simpan_biodata",
   data : string,
   cache : false,
   dataType  : 'json',
   
   beforeSend : function(){
             //lakukan apasaja sambil menunggu proses selesai disini
             //misal tampilkan loading
             
             $(".loading").html("Please wait....");
             
           },

   success : function(data){
    if(data.status != 'error'){
        window.location.assign("<?php echo site_url();?>/peserta/home/foto")
             }
             alert(data.msg);
   }
  });
  //return false();
  
 });
 
});



</script>
```

and this is my form

```html
<div class="ui-widget">
  <div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all">
    <p align="justify">
    <strong><?php echo $judul;?></strong></p>
  </div>
</div>
<form id="my-form" name="my-form" method="POST" action="#">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<tbody>

<tr>
 <td colspan="8"><h5>Kode Dokumen: </h5> &nbsp;<input type="text" 
 style="
 background: #fef556;
 font-size: 20px;
 height: 20px;
 color: #fd1711;
 " name="KodeDokumen" value="<?php echo $nomor;?>" readonly=""></input><p align="justify"><font color="red" size="2pt"><b>(Simpan kode ini dan gunakan untuk melihat status dokumen anda)</b></font></p></td>
 
</tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="2"><h4>A. Jenis Dokumen</h4></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="span4">Jenis Dokumen<span style="color: red"><b>*</b></span></br>
 <font style="calibri" color="red">(Wajib diisi)</font></td>
 <td><input type="radio" class="cek" name="jenisDokumen" Value="Lapor Diri"> Lapor Diri </input></br>
 <input type="radio" class="cek" name="jenisDokumen" Value="Pembuatan Paspor Baru"> Pembuatan Paspor Baru </input></br>
 <input type="radio" class="cek" name="jenisDokumen" Value="Perpanjangan Paspor"> Perpanjangan Paspor </input></br>
 <input type="radio" class="cek" name="jenisDokumen" Value="Perubahan Data Paspor"> Perubahan Data Paspor </input></br>
 <input type="radio" class="cek" name="jenisDokumen" Value="Surat Keterangan / dll"> Surat Keterangan / dll </input></td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2"><h4>B. Informasi Data Diri Pemohon</h4></td>
</tr> 
   
<tr>
 <td class="span4">1. Nama Lengkap</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="namaLengkap" id="namaLengkap" class="span4"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>2. Tempat/Tanggal Lahir</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="tempatLahirPemohon" id="tempatLahirPemohon" class="span3">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tglLahirPemohon" id="tglLahirPemohon" class="span2"> *) Format : tgl-bln-thn</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>3. Jenis Kelamin</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="jenisKelaminPemohon" Value="Pria"> Pria &nbsp;<input type="radio" name="jenisKelaminPemohon" value="Wanita"> Wanita</input></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>4. Status</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="statusPemohon" Value="Nikah"> Nikah&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="statusPemohon" value="Belum Nikah"> Belum Nikah&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="statusPemohon" value="J"> Janda&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="statusPemohon" value="D"> Duda  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>5. Agama</td>
 <td>
  <select name="agamaPemohon" id="agamaPemohon" class="span2">
   <option value="">-PILIH-</option>
   <option value="Islam">Islam</option>
   <option value="Kristen">Kristen</option>
   <option value="Katolik">Katolik</option>
   <option value="Hindu">Hindu</option>
   <option value="Buddha">Buddha</option>
            <option value="Lain-lain">Lain-lain</option>
  </select>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td class="span4">6. Nama Suami/Istri</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="namaSuamiIstriPemohon" id="namaSuamiIstriPemohon" class="span4"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>7. Tempat/Tanggal Lahir Istri/Suami</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="tempatLhrSuamiIstriPemohon" id="tempatLhrSuamiIstriPemohon" class="span3">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon" id="tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon" class="span2"> *) Format : tgl-bln-thn</td>
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>8. Kewarganegaraan Istri/Suami</td>
 <td>
  <select name="kewarganegaraanSuamiIstriPemohon" id="kewarganegaraanSuamiIstriPemohon" class="span2">
   <option value="WNI">WNI</option>
   <option value="WNA">WNA</option>
  </select>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td class="span4">9. Jenis Paspor</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="jenisPaspor" Value="Biasa"> Biasa&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="jenisPaspor" value="Dinas"> Dinas&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="jenisPaspor" value="Diplomatik"> Diplomatik&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Nomor:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="nomorPaspor" id="nomorPaspor" class="span3"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>10. Tempat/Tanggal Pengeluaran</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="tempatKeluarPaspor" id="tempatKeluarPaspor" class="span3">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tglKeluarPaspor" id="tglKeluarPaspor" class="span2"> *) Format : tgl-bln-thn</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>11. Masa Berlaku Hingga</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="masaBerlakuPaspor" id="masaBerlakuPaspor" class="span2"> *) Format : tgl-bln-thn</td>
</tr>


<tr>
 <td class="span4">12. Jenis Visa Amerika</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="jenisVisaAmerika" Value="Permanent Resident"> Permanent Resident&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="jenisVisaAmerika" value="Lain-lain"> Lain-lain&nbsp;<input type="text" name="visaAmerikaLain" id="visaAmerikaLain" class="span2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Nomor:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="nomorVisaAmerika" id="nomorVisaAmerika" class="span2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>13. Masa Berlaku Hingga</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="masaBerlakuVisa" id="masaBerlakuVisa" class="span2"> *) Format : tgl-bln-thn</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td class="span4">14. Kartu Ijin Tinggal di Amerika</td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="jenisKartuIjinTinggal" Value="I-94"> I-94&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="jenisKartuIjinTinggal" Value="I-20"> I-20&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="radio" name="jenisKartuIjinTinggal" value="Lain-lain"> Lain-lain&nbsp;<input type="text" name="kartuIzinLain" id="kartuIzinLain" class="span2">&nbsp;&nbsp;Nomor:&nbsp;<input type="text" name="nomorKartuIjinTinggal" id="nomorKartuIjinTinggal" class="span2"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>15. Masa Berlaku Hingga</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="masaBerlakuKartu" id="masaBerlakuKartu" class="span2"> *) Format : tgl-bln-thn</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td class="span4">16. Pekerjaan</br>
 <p align="justify"><font size="2pt" color="red">(Agar ditandai seakurat mungkin, apabila tidak ada kategorinya, dapat disebutkan Lain-lain)</font></p></td>
 <td>
  <table class="table-bordered">
  <tr>
   <td class="span3">
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Dokter"> Dokter</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Dosen"> Dosen</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Pengacara"> Pengacara</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Pilot"> Pilot</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Pramugari/a"> Pramugari/a</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Pengusaha"> Pengusaha</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Perminyakan"> Perminyakan</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Pertambangan"> Pertambangan</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Konstruksi"> Konstruksi</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Industri(Laki-laki)"> Industri(Laki-laki)</input></br>
   </td>
   
   <td class="span3">
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Industri(Wanita)"> Industri(Wanita)</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Perkebunan"> Perkebunan</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Chauffeur"> Chauffeur</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Chauffeur/Delivery"> Chauffeur/Delivery</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="PLRT/Helper"> PLRT/Helper</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Babysitter"> Babysitter</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Caregiver/Nurse"> Caregiver/Nurse</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Petugas Kebersihan"> Petugas Kebersihan</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Pertokoan"> Pertokoan</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Perhotelan/Wisata"> Perhotelan/Wisata</input></br>
   </td>
   
   <td class="span3">
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Restaurant"> Restaurant</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="SPBU/Gas Station"> SPBU/Gas Station</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Mahasiswa/Pelajar"> Mahasiswa/Pelajar</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Ibu Rumah Tangga"> Ibu Rumah Tangga</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Kapal Pesiar"> Kapal Pesiar</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Kapal Cargo"> Kapal Cargo</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Kapal Ikan"> Kapal Ikan</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Kapal Tanker"> Kapal Tanker</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Rohaniawan/wati"> Rohaniawan/wati</input></br>
   <input type="checkbox" name="pekerjaanPemohon" Value="Lain-lain"> Lain-lain</input></br>
   </td>
   
   </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>17. Nama Perusahaan/Sekolah</td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" name="namaPerusahaanSekolahPem" id="namaPerusahaanSekolahPem" class="span6">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>18. Alamat Perusahaan/Sekolah</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="alamatPerusahaanSekolahPem1" id="alamatPerusahaanSekolahPem1" class="span8">
  <input type="text" name="alamatPerusahaanSekolahPem2" id="alamatPerusahaanSekolahPem2" class="span8">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>19. Alamat Rumah</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="alamatRumahPem1" id="alamatRumahPem1" class="span8">
  <input type="text" name="alamatRumahPem2" id="alamatRumahPem2" class="span8">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>20. Nomor Telepon</td>
 <td>
 
 <table class="table-bordered">
  <tr>
   <td class="span3">Rumah </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="telpRumahPem" id="telpRumahPem" class="span3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="span3">Kantor/Tempat Bekerja </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="telpKantorPem" id="telpKantorPem" class="span3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="span3">Cellular </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="hpPemohon" id="hpPemohon" class="span3"></td
  </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>21. Email</td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" name="emailPemohon" id="emailPemohon" class="span6">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="3"><h4>C. Informasi Keluarga di <b><u>Amerika</u></b>/Kontak Dalam Keadaan Darurat (Family/Emergency Contact)</h4></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>22. Nama</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="namaKeluargaAmerika" id="namaKeluargaAmerika" class="span3"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
 <td>23. Alamat di Amerika</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="alamatAmerika1" id="alamatAmerika1" class="span8">
  <input type="text" name="alamatAmerika2" id="alamatAmerika2" class="span8">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>24. Nomor Telepon</td>
 <td>
 
 <table class="table-bordered">
  <tr>
   <td class="span3">Rumah </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="noTelRumahAmerika" id="noTelRumahAmerika" class="span3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="span3">Kantor/Tempat Bekerja </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="noTelKantorAmerika" id="noTelKantorAmerika" class="span3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="span3">Cellular </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="noCelAmerika" id="noCelAmerika" class="span3"></td
  </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>25. Email</td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" name="emailAmerika" id="emailAmerika" class="span6">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="3"><h4>D. Informasi Keluarga di <b><u>Indonesia</u></b>/Kontak Dalam Keadaan Darurat (Family/Emergency Contact)</h4></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>26. Nama</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="namaKeluargaIndonesia" id="namaKeluargaIndonesia" class="span3"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
 <td>27. Alamat di Amerika</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="alamatKeluargaIndonesia1" id="alamatKeluargaIndonesia1" class="span8">
  <input type="text" name="alamatKeluargaIndonesia2" id="alamatKeluargaIndonesia2" class="span8">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>28. Nomor Telepon</td>
 <td>
 
 <table class="table-bordered">
  <tr>
   <td class="span3">Rumah </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="noTelRumahIndonesia" id="noTelRumahIndonesia" class="span3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="span3">Kantor/Tempat Bekerja </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="noTelKantorIndonesia" id="noTelKantorIndonesia" class="span3"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="span3">Cellular </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="noCelIndonesia" id="noCelIndonesia" class="span3"></td
  </tr>
  </table>
 </td>
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>29. Email</td>
 <td>
  <input type="text" name="emailIndonesia" id="emailIndonesia" class="span6">
 </td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="3"><h4>E. Khusus Untuk Pengesahan Perubahan (Endorsement) di Dalam Paspor</h4></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>30. Data Yang Berubah</td>
 <td>
 <input type="radio" name="dataBerubah" Value="Nama"> Nama</input>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="radio" name="dataBerubah" Value="Alamat"> Alamat</input>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="radio" name="dataBerubah" Value="Pekerjaan"> Pekerjaan</input>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="radio" name="dataBerubah" Value="Status Sipil"> Status Sipil</input>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <input type="radio" name="dataBerubah" Value="Lain-lain"> Lain-lain</input></td>
 
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>31. Data Semula</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="berubahDari" id="berubahDari" class="span8"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
 <td>32. Data Dirubah Menjadi </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="berubahKe" id="berubahKe" class="span8"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="3"><h4>F. Khusus Untuk Pendataan Anak di Bawah Usia 18 Tahun</h4></td>
</tr>

<tr> 
 <td>33. Nama Ayah/No. Paspor </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="namaAyahNopaspor" id="namaAyahNopaspor" class="span8"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
 <td>34. Tempat/Tanggal Lahir </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="tempatLahirAyah" id="tempatLahirAyah" class="span3">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tanggalLahirAyah" id="tanggalLahirAyah" class="span2"> *) Format : tgl-bln-thn</td>
</tr>
<tr> 
 <td>35. Nama Ibu/No. Paspor </td>
 <td><input type="text" name="namaIbuNoPaspor" id="namaIbuNoPaspor" class="span8"></td>
</tr>
<tr> 
 <td>36. Tempat/Tanggal Lahir </td>
  <td><input type="text" name="tempatLahirIbu" id="tempatLahirIbu" class="span3">&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="tanggalLahirIbu" id="tanggalLahirIbu" class="span2"> *) Format : tgl-bln-thn</td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td colspan="2">Silahkan Klik Lanjut !!!</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
 <td colspan="2"><center>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>" class="btn btn-info"><i class="icon-off icon-white"></i> Batal</a>
    <button type="button" name="simpan" id="simpan" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return();"><i class="icon-hand-right icon-white"></i> Lanjut Ke Step 2</button>
    </center>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

and finally this is my php function for save the data in the controller of CI

```
    public function simpan_biodata()
{       

        date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Jakarta');
        $status = "";
        $msg = "";

        // convert tanggal 
        $tglLahirPemohon = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input->post('tglLahirPemohon'));
        $tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon'));
        $tglKeluarPaspor = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('tglKeluarPaspor'));
        $masaBerlakuPaspor = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('masaBerlakuPaspor'));
        $masaBerlakuVisa = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('masaBerlakuVisa'));
        $masaBerlakuKartu = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('masaBerlakuKartu'));
        $tanggalLahirAyah = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('tanggalLahirAyah'));
        $tanggalLahirIbu = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('tanggalLahirIbu'));




        $d['KodeDokumen'] = $this->input->post('KodeDokumen');
        $d['tglEntryDokumen'] = date('Y-m-d');//$this->input->post('');
        $d['jenisDokumen'] = $this->input->post('jenisDokumen');
        $d['namaLengkap'] = $this->input->post('namaLengkap');
        $d['tempatLahirPemohon'] = $this->input->post('tempatLahirPemohon');
        $d['tglLahirPemohon'] = $tglLahirPemohon;
        $d['jenisKelaminPemohon'] = $this->input->post('jenisKelaminPemohon');
        $d['statusPemohon'] = $this->input->post('statusPemohon ');
        $d['agamaPemohon'] = $this->input->post('agamaPemohon');
        $d['namaSuamiIstriPemohon'] = $this->input->post('namaSuamiIstriPemohon');
        $d['tempatLhrSuamiIstriPemohon'] = $this->input->post('tempatLhrSuamiIstriPemohon');
        $d['tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon'] = $tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon;
        $d['kewarganegaraanSuamiIstriPemohon'] = $this->input->post('kewarganegaraanSuamiIstriPemohon');
        $d['jenisPaspor'] = $this->input->post('jenisPaspor');
        $d['nomorPaspor'] = $this->input->post('nomorPaspor');
        $d['tempatKeluarPaspor'] = $this->input->post('tempatKeluarPaspor');
        $d['tglKeluarPaspor'] = $tglKeluarPaspor;
        $d['masaBerlakuPaspor'] = $masaBerlakuPaspor;
        $d['jenisVisaAmerika'] = $this->input->post('jenisVisaAmerika');
        $d['visaAmerikaLain'] = $this->input->post('visaAmerikaLain');
        $d['nomorVisaAmerika'] = $this->input->post('nomorVisaAmerika');
        $d['masaBerlakuVisa'] = $this->input->post('masaBerlakuVisa'); 
        $d['jenisKartuIjinTinggal'] = $this->input->post('jenisKartuIjinTinggal');
        $d['kartuIzinLain'] = $this->input->post('kartuIzinLain');
        $d['nomorKartuIjinTinggal'] = $this->input->post('nomorKartuIjinTinggal');
        $d['masaBerlakuKartu'] = $this->input->post('masaBerlakuKartu');
        $d['pekerjaanPemohon'] = $this->input->post('pekerjaanPemohon');
        $d['namaPerusahaanSekolahPem'] = $this->input->post('namaPerusahaanSekolahPem');
        $d['alamatPerusahaanSekolahPem1'] = $this->input->post('alamatPerusahaanSekolahPem1');
        $d['alamatPerusahaanSekolahPem2'] = $this->input->post('alamatPerusahaanSekolahPem2');
        $d['alamatRumahPem1'] = $this->input->post('alamatRumahPem1');
        $d['alamatRumahPem2'] = $this->input->post('alamatRumahPem2');
        $d['telpRumahPem'] = $this->input->post('telpRumahPem');
        $d['telpKantorPem'] = $this->input->post('telpKantorPem');
        $d['hpPemohon'] = $this->input->post('hpPemohon');
        $d['emailPemohon'] = $this->input->post('emailPemohon');
        $d['namaKeluargaAmerika'] = $this->input->post('namaKeluargaAmerika');
        $d['alamatAmerika1'] = $this->input->post('alamatAmerika1');
        $d['alamatAmerika2'] = $this->input->post('alamatAmerika2');
        $d['noTelRumahAmerika'] = $this->input->post('noTelRumahAmerika');
        $d['noTelKantorAmerika'] = $this->input->post('noTelKantorAmerika');
        $d['noCelAmerika'] = $this->input->post('noCelAmerika');
        $d['emailAmerika'] = $this->input->post('emailAmerika');
        $d['namaKeluargaIndonesia'] = $this->input->post('namaKeluargaIndonesia');
        $d['alamatKeluargaIndonesia1'] = $this->input->post('alamatKeluargaIndonesia1');
        $d['alamatKeluargaIndonesia2'] = $this->input->post('alamatKeluargaIndonesia2');
        $d['noTelRumahIndonesia'] = $this->input->post('noTelRumahIndonesia');
        $d['noTelKantorIndonesia'] = $this->input->post('noTelKantorIndonesia');
        $d['noCelIndonesia'] = $this->input->post('noCelIndonesia');
        $d['emailIndonesia'] = $this->input->post('emailIndonesia');
        $d['dataBerubah'] = $this->input->post('dataBerubah');
        $d['berubahDari'] = $this->input->post('berubahDari');
        $d['berubahKe'] = $this->input->post('berubahKe');
        $d['namaAyahNopaspor'] = $this->input->post('namaAyahNopaspor');
        $d['tempatLahirAyah'] = $this->input->post('tempatLahirAyah');
        $d['tanggalLahirAyah'] = $this->input->post('tanggalLahirAyah');
        $d['namaIbuNoPaspor'] = $this->input->post('namaIbuNoPaspor');
        $d['tempatLahirIbu'] = $this->input->post('tempatLahirIbu');
        $d['tanggalLahirIbu'] = $this->input->post('tanggalLahirIbu');

        $this->app_model->insertData("tbpemohon",$d);
        $status="sukses";
        $msg="Data Sukses disimpan";
        echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'msg' => $msg));

}
```

this is my model

class App_Model extends CI_Model {

```
public function getAllData($table)
{
    return $this->db->get($table);
}

public function getAllDataLimited($table,$limit,$offset)
{
    return $this->db->get($table, $limit, $offset);
}

public function getSelectedDataLimited($table,$data,$limit,$offset)
{
    return $this->db->get_where($table, $data, $limit, $offset);
}

//select table
public function getSelectedData($table,$data)
{
    return $this->db->get_where($table, $data);
}
//update table
function updateData($table,$data,$field_key)
{
    $this->db->update($table,$data,$field_key);
}
function deleteData($table,$data)
{
    $this->db->delete($table,$data);
}

function insertData($table,$data)
{
    $this->db->insert($table,$data);
}
```

}

Thankfully for your help.

best regards

Nanang

Comment: Do you get any error

Comment: no... i not found error notification, what my code is true?

Comment: Try to simply your question with lesser codes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this solution.

```
var fd = new FormData(document.getElementById("my-form"));

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo site_url('peserta/home/simpan_biodata'); ?>",
    data:fd,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
    contentType: false ,  // tell jQuery not to set contentType
    success:function(data){
        //var str = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(data);
    },
    error:function(err){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks all, I found the source code in controller was wrong

Answer (score 0):

yeah..thanks for your all, I found is my code was wrong

```
 // convert tanggal 
    $tglLahirPemohon = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input->post('tglLahirPemohon'));
    $tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon'));
    $tglKeluarPaspor = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('tglKeluarPaspor'));
    $masaBerlakuPaspor = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('masaBerlakuPaspor'));
    $masaBerlakuVisa = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('masaBerlakuVisa'));
    $masaBerlakuKartu = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('masaBerlakuKartu'));
    $tanggalLahirAyah = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('tanggalLahirAyah'));
    $tanggalLahirIbu = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input('tanggalLahirIbu'));
```

and the correct code is

```
            $tglLahirPemohon = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input->post('tglLahirPemohon'));
        $tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input->post('tglLahirSuamiIstriPemohon'));
        $tglKeluarPaspor = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input->post('tglKeluarPaspor'));
        $masaBerlakuPaspor = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input->post('masaBerlakuPaspor'));
        $masaBerlakuVisa = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input->post('masaBerlakuVisa'));
        $masaBerlakuKartu = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input->post('masaBerlakuKartu'));
        $tanggalLahirAyah = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input->post('tanggalLahirAyah'));
        $tanggalLahirIbu = $this->app_model->tgl_sql($this->input->post('tanggalLahirIbu'));
```

thanks you so much